# How do I combine 2 indicators into one set of 'buy' & 'sell' signals in Pine Editor on TradingView? (DeMark9 & MACD for example)

Tags: cryptography, pine-script, trading, binance, tradingview-api

I would like to combine 2 indicators to trigger 'buy' or 'sell' signals in Pine Editor on TradingView.

At the moment I have code for Demark9 indicator but I would like to combine with a secondary indicator under the same 'IF' statement.

For example:

**BUY**: If Demark9 location.belowbar is `TRUE` **AND** MACD indicator is `TRUE` THEN plot 'Buy' signal on chart.

**SELL**: If Demark9 location.abovebar is `TRUE` **AND** MACD indicator is `TRUE` THEN 'Sell' signal.

Below is the code that currently works but I want to add an additional indicator into the same buy or sell signal:

```
//DeMark_9_Indicator_1
study("Nathan's Bot Indicator",overlay=true)
TD = close > close[4] ?nz(TD[1])+1:0
TS = close < close[4] ?nz(TS[1])+1:0
TDUp = TD - valuewhen(TD < TD[1], TD , 1 )
TDDn = TS - valuewhen(TS < TS[1], TS , 1 )
plotshape(TDUp==7?true:na,style=shape.triangledown,text="7",color=green,location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(TDUp==8?true:na,style=shape.triangledown,text="8",color=green,location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(TDUp==9?true:na,style=shape.triangledown,text="⚠️",color=green,location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(TDDn==7?true:na,style=shape.triangleup,text="7",color=red,location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(TDDn==8?true:na,style=shape.triangleup,text="8",color=red,location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(TDDn==9?true:na,style=shape.triangleup,text="✅",color=red,location=location.belowbar)
```

Any help is super appreciated.

THANK YOU UNIVERSE

Comment: You'll have to be clearer with what you mean regarding the MACD condition. Above/below the zero line? the signal line?

Answer (score 0):

You just need to use the `and` operator and import the MACD indicator. You can see the source code for the MACD by clicking the code icon on MACD.
Copy paste the macd into your script.

```
//macd
macd_fast = 12, macd_slow = 26
macd_fastMA = ema(close, macd_fast)
macd_slowMA = ema(close, macd_slow)
macd = macd_fastMA - macd_slowMA
macd_signal = sma(macd, 9)
macd_hist = macd - macd_signal
```

Then add your conditions for macd example:

```
macd_buy = macd_hist > 0
macd_sell = macd_hist < 0
```

And then you can just use the `and` operator to combine the two conditions. The final source code would be:

```
//DeMark_9_Indicator_1
study("Nathan's Bot Indicator",overlay=true)
TD = close > close[4] ?nz(TD[1])+1:0
TS = close < close[4] ?nz(TS[1])+1:0
TDUp = TD - valuewhen(TD < TD[1], TD , 1 )
TDDn = TS - valuewhen(TS < TS[1], TS , 1 )

//macd
macd_fast = 12, macd_slow = 26
macd_fastMA = ema(close, macd_fast)
macd_slowMA = ema(close, macd_slow)
macd = macd_fastMA - macd_slowMA
macd_signal = sma(macd, 9)
macd_hist = macd - macd_signal

macd_buy = macd_hist > 0
macd_sell = macd_hist < 0

plotshape(TDUp==7 and macd_sell ?true:na,style=shape.triangledown,text="7",color=green,location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(TDUp==8 and macd_sell ?true:na,style=shape.triangledown,text="8",color=green,location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(TDUp==9 and macd_sell ?true:na,style=shape.triangledown,text="⚠️",color=green,location=location.abovebar)
plotshape(TDDn==7 and macd_buy ?true:na,style=shape.triangleup,text="7",color=red,location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(TDDn==8 and macd_buy ?true:na,style=shape.triangleup,text="8",color=red,location=location.belowbar)
plotshape(TDDn==9 and macd_buy ?true:na,style=shape.triangleup,text="✅",color=red,location=location.belowbar)
```